# Why () are needed in this Javascript code block?

Tags: javascript, brackets

I understand there are many pitfall in javascript, but I still don't understand there are any difference between expression a&1 and (a&1) ??

the following code tries covert 11 (10 base) to a string 1101 (2 base)

```
<script>
var str = '';
var a = 11;
for(var i=0;a;i++){
    str = a & 1 + str; // this doesn't work must rewrite as 
    // str = (a & 1) + str;
    console.log('str = ' + str);
    a >>>=1;
}
console.log(str);
</script>
```

Comment: Just so you know, there's a built-in: `(11).toString(2)`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is because of [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)

The [Addition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Addition) has a higher precedence than [Bitwise AND](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_AND). So when `a & 1 + str` is evaluated the `1 + str` is evaluated first then `a & result` is evaluated.

Using [Grouping Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Grouping) we can change the evaluation order. So when `(a & 1) + str` is evaluated, contents inside `()` (`a & 1`) is evaluated first `result + str` is evaluated.